# Use Laravel Controller in simple php file

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple .php file:

```
$ffs = glob("*.zip");
foreach($ffs as $ff){
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($ff) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('./');
        $zip->close();
    }
  *RUN METHOD FROM LARAVEL CONTROLLER OUTSIDE APP DIR*
}
```

Now I want to run controller method from Laravel. Is this possible?

Comment: Controller method from laravel? As in `routes.php`?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi yes. I have url in routes.php to this method.

Comment: @OSNam what is your goal, it sounds like your not using laravel as expected.

Comment: Do you mean to run this method inside a particular controller? Or bind this method to a route?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi i have website. Once a day I recive .zip folder from ftp client. I want to unzip this file and then run method from controller which will control data received from ftp.

Comment: So basically you want to execute this method at a particular time on daily basis without invoking an endpoint right?

Comment: If the answer is yes, have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling